# Shell script to check dir directory if it exists then change the path, if not then create dir with that name and also check for file name not exists

Tags: unix, path, directory, exists

How to write a Shell script to check a directory and if it exists then change the path, if not then create dir with that name?(Using nano editor)

Comment: Please provide what you've tried and what error you got while doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a directory exists you can use the below test:

```bash
[ ! -d "$DIRNAME" ]
```

The complete script:

```bash
if [ ! -d "${DIRNAME}" ]; then
   mkdir ${DIRNAME}
fi
cd ${DIRNAME}
```

Another solution could be create however the directory with -p option that does not return error if it exists:

```bash
mkdir -p ${DIRNAME}
cd ${DIRNAME}
```